# Software/scripts to create historical database?

Tags: sql, database, etl, data-warehouse

We use several information systems, each with its own underlying relational database. These databases do not always keep track of history. When a record changes the old information is lost. For various reasons (auditability, data mining) we would like to keep track of the full history of each database in a central place.

To this end, i want to use this simple approach: Just copy all databases into a single new database histDb, and add two columns to each table: openDate and closeDate. Each day, query all source databases and look for rows that have changed. If so, close the corresponding record in histDb and create a new copy-record with the new values. In the closed record, closeDate will be set to [today], in the new record, openDate will be set to [today].

(I'm assuming daily tracking of changes is frequent enough. If not one could envision using triggers but that's out of scope for now.)

**QUESTION**: Is there software that automates generating/loading such a historical database? Preferrably, it should `talk to' all major dbms-es so it can read from many source systems, it should be easy to use and open source.

I'd like to collect history on as many sources as possible with as little effort as possible.

All pointers appreciated. TIA.

Mike

Comment: While economy of effort is always admirable, the relevant cliché for this situation is, "You get out of it what you put into it.".

Comment: Agree generally. But this problem is conceptually so simple: Just find the delta's in a bunch of tables, no matter how many, what their names are and what columns/types. There must surely be a script/software that does this for me?